# Differential Equations Of the Form $y'(t) =Ay(t) +b(t)$. My attempt using a theorem$ (y(t) = e^{tA}\int e{-tA}b(t)dt$)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let the following differential equation:

$$y'(t) =   \begin{pmatrix}
  -3 & 10 \\
   -3 & 8
\end{pmatrix} y(t) + \begin{pmatrix}
  1 \\
   t
\end{pmatrix}$$

I know that in the case where the differential equation is of the form:

$y'(t)=Ay(t)$ then we simply have $y(t) =e^{At}y(0)$ But I don't know what to do in the my case.

**Attempt at solution**

A theorem states that the solution of an ODE of the form: $y'(t) = Ay(t) +b(t)$ is : $y(t) = e^{tA}\int  e{-tA}b(t)dt$

With $A = \begin{pmatrix}
  -3 & 10 \\
   -3 & 8
\end{pmatrix}$

and $b(t) = \begin{pmatrix}
  1 \\
   t
\end{pmatrix}$

Let us compute $e^{At}$ (i will just provide the answer for I strongly believe it to be right):

$e^{tA} = \begin{pmatrix}
  -5e^{2t}+6e^{3t} & 10(e^{3t}-e^{2t}) \\
   3(e^{2t}-e^{3t}) & 6e^{3t}-5e^{2t}
\end{pmatrix}$

Therefore, $e^{-At}b(t) = \begin{pmatrix}
  -5e^{2t}+6e^{3t} & 10(e^{3t}-e^{2t}) \\
   3(e^{2t}-e^{3t}) & 6e^{3t}-5e^{2t}
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
  1 \\
   t
\end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix}
  -5e^{-2t}+6e^{-3t} + 10t(e^{-3t}-e^{-2t}) \\
   3(e^{-2t}-e^{-3t}) + 6te^{-3t}-5te^{-2t}
\end{pmatrix} $

And $\int   \begin{pmatrix}
  -5e^{-2t}+6e^{-3t} + 10t(e^{-3t}-e^{-2t}) \\
   3(e^{-2t}-e^{-3t}) + 6te^{-3t}-5te^{-2t}
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
  \dfrac{15}{2}e^{-2t} - \dfrac{16}{3}e^{-3t} \\
   e^{-2t}-e^{-3t}
\end{pmatrix} $

Therefore: $y(t) = \begin{pmatrix}
  -5e^{2t}+6e^{3t} & 10(e^{3t}-e^{2t}) \\
   3(e^{2t}-e^{3t}) & 6e^{3t}-5e^{2t}
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
  \dfrac{15}{2}e^{-2t} - \dfrac{16}{3}e^{-3t} \\
   e^{-2t}-e^{-3t}
\end{pmatrix}  =$ some kind of crazy result

**Am I heading in the right direction: this seems totally crazy and completely computational**

Also, it seems bizarre that $y \in \mathbb{R^2}$

Comment: (1) Your solution of $y'(t) = Ay(t)$ is incorrect. (2) Integrating factors give the following: write $z(t) = e^{-At} y(t)$. We have $$ z'(t) = e^{-At} y'(t) - e^{-At} A y(t) = e^{-At} b(t) $$ Now just integrate.

Comment: I meant $y(t) = e^{At}y(0)$, I edited the question

Comment: Are $A$ and $b$ scalars?

Comment: A is a 2$\times$ 2 matrix and in my case $b \in \mathbb{R^2}$

Comment: What I outlined in my first comment falls under the larger umbrella of the method of [variation of constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters), which allows you to find solutions to the inhomogeneous problem given the solution to the homogeneous problem.

Comment: Is it always true that in inhomogenous equations, the final solution of y is $y_p+y_c$     ,  $y_p$ being the particular solution and $y_c$ the complimentary solution?

Comment: @aribaldi: of course. If you plug $y_p$ in the equation, you satisfy it, and if you subtract memberwise, you see that $y-y_c$ satisfies the homogenous equation.

Answer (score 0):

This is a comment, since I haven't reached 50 reputations.

According to Dr. Wong's method, we can derive

\begin{equation}
y(t) = e^{At} y(0) + \int_0^t e^{A(t-\tau)} b(\tau) d \tau,
\end{equation}
where $b(\tau) = [1~\tau]^T$.

Actually, the term $[1~t]^T$ is convoluted by the original differential equation without this term.

The whole proof can be found in Section 4.2 in "Linear System Theory and Design" by Chi Tsong Chen in 1999.

Comment: What is "control theory" in there?

Comment: Sorry, I have deleted the control theory part, since it would be related to one's background.@Did